# GET запрос с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте! Знаю как отправлять `ajax` запросы методом POST, но не знаю как отправлять методом GET (т.е. надо чтобы и в адресной строке все менялось, и если я скопирую ссылку и отправлю кому-то, то он тоже мог зайти на эту страницу).Как это реализовать и вообще имеет ли это смысл? Или все таки просты GET запросы (без `ajax`) куда лучше?

Comment: Если вам надо целиком заменить страницу новым контентом, то смысла в аяксе нет. если вы хотите поменять часть контента (например, какие нить динамические табы, фильтры и т.п.) то аяксом тянете изменившийся контент, а URL в браузере меняете через history api. Сами по себе GET-запросы в данном контексте вообще не при чем.

Comment: Ссылка на аджакс не имеет смысла, копируйте ссылку на страницу с которой делается аджакс.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что `GET` не влияет на ссылку он влияет на то какой запрос отправляется на сервер и если скрит обрабатывает `GET` запрос то используй `GET` а если `POST` то используй `POST` **это влияет только на метод передачи данных**